# A question about simple arcs in higher dimensional Euclidean spaces.

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let E(n) be n-dimensional Euclidean space. It is known that there exist subsets of E(n) which are
simple arcs and have positive n-dimensional Lebesgue measure when n=1 or 2. Does this continue to
be true for arbitrarily large n? If not, what is the largest n for which it holds and is there a
simple proof of this fact? Intuitively, I feel that there should be no upper bound, but cannot see
how to prove it.

Comment: Yes (this is so for every $n=1\ 2\ \ldots$).

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. I have searched extensively to find it
in the literature but with no success.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/228819/two-questions-about-the-extent-to-which-simple-arcs-and-simple-closed-curves-can